# insert unrelated values from multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I have an app that reads from multiple mysql tables, but I'd like to put all the data into 1 table. Thing is, these tables have no linking fields... the app just sequentially processes the rows across the 3 tables, with the hope that the correct rows are lined up in each table (i.e. that row1 in table1 is applicable to row1 in table 2 and table3, and so on)

My tables are as follows:

Table1:
Name,Surname,ID,DoB

Table2:
Address,Town,State

Table3:
password

What I want is :
Table4:
Name,Surname,ID,DoB,Address,Town,State,password

I have created Table4 and I'm now trying to insert the values with a select query...
I've tried ...

```
SELECT
t1.Name,
t1.Surname,
t1.ID,
t1.DoB,
t2.Address,
t2.Town,
t2.State,
t3.password
FROM table1 AS t1,table2 AS t2, table3 AS t3;
```

...but this gives me duplicate rows cos there is no where clause. And since there's no linking fields, i can't use a JOIN statement, right?
I'm not a very experienced with SQL, so please help!

Comment: How do you know which address in Table2 belongs to which user in Table1?

Comment: I rely on the order in which it was inserted, hoping that the lines were added correctly (i.e. the 10th line on table2 is relevant to the 10th line on Table1 and Table3). Sadly, I inherited this app from a predecessor at my job, so it's not my design. This is why i am trying to get it all into one table!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, officialy you're messed up. There is no first or last row in a RDBMS unless you use an `ORDER BY` clause. That's also what the manual states. If you issue a

```
SELECT * FROM your_table;
```

you can not be sure to get the result in the same order the rows were inserted or in the same order every time you issue the statement at all.

In practice on the other hand, most of the time you will get the same result and most of the time even in the same order the rows were inserted.

What you can do, is, to first slap the one who didn't think of putting a column in each table that determines a sort order (in the future use either an auto_increment column or a timestamp column that holds the date and time of insertion or whatever suits your needs) and second, (but really do this only if you have no other choice, as like I said it's unreliable) you can emulate a row number on which you can join.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT table1.*, @rn1 := @rn1 + 1 as row_number FROM 
    table1, 
    (SELECT @rn1 := 0) v
) a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT table2.*, @rn2 := @rn2 + 1 as row_number FROM 
    table2, 
    (SELECT @rn2 := 0) v
) b ON a.row_number = b.row_number
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT table3.*, @rn3 := @rn3 + 1 as row_number FROM 
    table3, 
    (SELECT @rn3 := 0) v
) c ON a.row_number = c.row_number
```

Comment: I'll give it a try... like I said in a previous comment, I inherited this app and I'm trying to modify it to fix any cr@p. This is why I want it all in one table. I actually re-coded the entore thing from scratch and only kept the DB cos it contains the data. Now i want to re-design the DB as well so that it works properly.

Comment: @hashimalkabaaz Made some adjustments to variable names and joins. Please try again.

Comment: Sir, you are a legend! It works perfectly. Now to figure out what the hell just happened there! Thank you!! Is there any way to mark this question as "resolved"?

Comment: @hashimalkabaaz Yes, by clicking the check left to my answer. Here's also a quick guide to this site: http://stackoverflow.com/tour